# Nightly build - do we delete files in "target" first?

Tags: java, maven

Folks,

As part of my nightly build for a Java application, I do the following:

```
$ cd dirContainingPOM.XML
$ svn update
$ rm -rf target
$ mvn package
```

Essentially, I get the latest version of the source code, delete all the files in the target directory, and build the jar package.

The question I have is if it is a good practice to delete everything in "target" directory or is it just an overkill. Is maven doing it automatically for me?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Regards,
Peter

Comment: This is a very good question, but I think it should be moved to programmers.stackexchange.com.

Comment: +1 to the answer; IMO it's really important to do clean builds, otherwise cruft can be left around from previous builds. Locally you can get away without it--sometimes--if you know what you've been changing. The CI box doesn't know enough. Heck, *I* don't know enough sometimes; been bitten by not cleaning more times than I care to admit.

Comment: should be moved to programmers.SE

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a good practice but you easily achieve the same thing by specifying the clean target in your maven command.

Instead of performing ...

```
mvn package
```

Try the following ...

```
mvn clean package
```

This will effectively negate the need to perform the rm -rf on your target directory.